# Is it bad practice to add helpers for IO operations in Go?

Tags: go, io, helper

I come from a C# background and am used IO methods like `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` from the `System.IO` namespace. I was a bit surprised to learn that Go didn't have convenience functions for these IO operations. In an effort to avoid code duplication, I wrote the below helpers. Is there any reason to not do this?

```golang
// WriteBytes writes the passed in bytes to the specified file. Before writing,
// if the file already exists, deletes all of its content; otherwise, creates
// the file.
func WriteBytes(filepath string, bytes []byte) (err error) {
    file, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer closeWithErrorPropagation(file, &err)

    _, err = file.Write(bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return err
}

// WriteString writes the passed in sting to the specified file. Before writing,
// if the file already exists, deletes all of its content; otherwise, creates
// the file.
func WriteString(filepath string, text string) (err error) {
    file, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer closeWithErrorPropagation(file, &err)

    _, err = file.WriteString(text)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return err
}

// WriteLines writes the passed in lines to the specified file. Before writing,
// if the file already exists, deletes all of its content; otherwise, creates
// the file.
func WriteLines(filepath string, lines []string) (err error) {
    file, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer closeWithErrorPropagation(file, &err)

    for _, line := range lines {
        _, err := file.WriteString(fmt.Sprintln(line))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return err
}

func closeWithErrorPropagation(c io.Closer, err *error) {
    if closerErr := c.Close(); closerErr != nil && *err == nil { // Only propagate the closer error if there isn't already an earlier error.
        *err = closerErr
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[os.WriteFile](https://pkg.go.dev/os#WriteFile) can handle the equivalent functionality of `WriteBytes` and `WriteString` functions:

```
// func WriteBytes(filepath string, bytes []byte) (err error)

err = os.WriteFile("testdata/hello", []byte("Hello, Gophers!"), 0666)


// func WriteString(filepath string, text string) (err error)

text := "Hello, Gophers!"
err = os.WriteFile("testdata/hello", []byte(text), 0666)
```

and combined with [strings.Join](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Join) can handle `WriteLines`:

```
//func WriteLines(filepath string, lines []string) (err error)

lines := []string{"hello", "gophers!"}
err = os.WriteFile("testdata/hello", []byte(strings.Join(lines, "\n")), 0666)
```

Comment: Additionally, assuming that `lines` is a slice of strings, `func WriteLines` could be replaced by
`os.WriteFile(outputFile, []byte(strings.Join(lines, "\n")), 0666)`

Comment: Was just about to add that :)